# Constraint to only allow users one record in each hour

Tags: mysql

I would like to create a time constraint on the datetime start and the datetime end so that you can only enter one appointment per hour on a calendar calendar in this form:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `color` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I tried this but it does not work:

```
alter table calendar 
  add constraint chk_HH_mm
    check( start( HH:mm ) >= end( HH:mm) && end( HH:mm) <= start( HH:mm ));
```

An ideas ?

Comment: Should you have a the user id in this constraint, too? Or location id?

Comment: Did mysql get support for check constraints?